# Dismiss modally presented view controller that is presenting another view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uimodalpresentationstyle

#### Overview

I have a root view controller (rootVC) and that view controller presents a view controller that contains some settings (VC1). This is using the page sheet presentation style, so it is presented like a card that is interactively dismissable by dragging down. Then, that view controller can present another view controller on top of it (VC2). That view controller is presented at only 25% of the screen height. It is just an informational view controller.

#### Question

The problem is that when VC1 is pulled down to dismiss it, if VC2 is presented, then VC1 cannot be dismissed without first manually dismissing VC2. Is there any way to allow VC1 to be dismissed (thereby dismissing VC2 in the process)?

#### Attempted Solutions

I have tried overriding these methods in VC1, but none of these actually seemed to be called when VC2 was presented on top of VC1.

```objectivec
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if (self.isBeingDismissed) {
        if (self.presentedViewController) {
            [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:animated completion:nil];
        }
    }
}

- (void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent {
    [super willMoveToParentViewController:parent];
    if (parent == nil) {
        if (self.presentedViewController) {
            [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
}

- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent {
    [super didMoveToParentViewController:parent];
    if (parent == nil) {
        if (self.presentedViewController) {
            [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add VC2's view as a subview of VC1 ... don't present it.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks so much for your reply and that would work, but that would require a lot of rearchitecting of the app because I actually have a lot of different view controllers that can present other view controllers and those view controllers can in turn present other view controllers. Is there any way to do this while still presenting the view controller? I tried using the UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate and the presentationControllerDidAttemptToDismiss: method is called, but that is only called after the dismissal is abandoned. Is there anything else that would work? Thank you.

Comment: Provide a complete, minimal example showing how you're presenting VC1 and presenting VC2 (at 25% of screen height).